# How to list multiple artists of the song?

Tags: python-3.x, spotipy

I am new to Spotipy, so I need help.

```
searched = sp.search(q=search, type="track", limit=1) 

artist = searched['tracks']['items'][0]['artists'][0]['name']
```

`search` is from  my Discord bot and it searches perfectly fine, all data here. But I couldn't figure out how to get all of the artists of the song. I know it has to do something with the `['0']` there because that just gets the first element. Any fixes?

Answer (score 0):

Try this and report back what the output looks like:

```
artist = searched['tracks']['items'][0]['artists']
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that artist is an array of all the artists of that song (the first one returned from search), from there you should be able to loop through this array to get all the artists of that song. I think it's then:

```
artist[i]['name']
```

that would give you the name of the artist.

It's possible that there is another key needed after ['artists'], if you output the value of artist to console you can work out the exact path to where you need to go.

I found a neat library that outputs dictionaries (and loads of other things) in a formatted way: pprint. I would recommend giving that a go and see if you can find it. i.e.

```
import pprint as p

p.pprint(artist)
```

The return from sp.search can be overwhelming at first, as it includes so much data (most of which you probably don't need), but I found looking at the dictionary with pprint was really helpful.